# How do I create a Document Property editable within the text in Word 2016?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I am creating a template document and I want to add a new/custom Document Property item that can be edited from the text like those available in the Insert > Quick Parts > Document Property menu.

Help on the Web shows how to create a Document Property which can be placed in the text as a greyed field that can be updated. However, the value of the document property is only editable in the "Advanced Properties" of the File > Info menu.

I want to create a Field which the user of the Word Document can easily edit on within the text. An example of this is in the image attached for the "Document Title" field.

The scope is that this document property can then be used as a field in headers/footers etc that has the value of what is inputted in the Control Field. Typical fields I want to add are: 'Report Number', 'Name of Client', etc.

Does anyone know how to create these fields?

[image: Example of the Control Field that I want to create]

Answer (score 4):

Insert > Quick Parts > Document Property does not insert fields. What it inserts is, as shown in your screenshot, a content control that is mapped to an xml part.

If you want to add your own custom properties you will need to create your own Custom XML Part and map the content controls in your document to it. If you do not know how to do this you may find the info on [Greg Maxey's website](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customXML_helpful_help.html) helpful

Comment: I ran these macros but it didn't add anything to 'Insert > Quick Parts > Document Property'

Answer (score 0):

I could do this using this [Tool](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_tools.html) . I clicked "Basic Mapping > Plain text". It won't appear in 'Insert > Quick Parts > Document Property' but only inside document.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft's walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-binding-content-controls-to-custom-xml-parts?view=vs-2017) goes about this very differently, using Visual Studio (which is not necessarily required), but it has a good example XML file, so I recommend you take a look at [that part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-binding-content-controls-to-custom-xml-parts?view=vs-2017#create-the-xml-data-file) of it at least.

So, first, you'll need to create an XML file which contains the properties you want to have available, so please look at [the appropriate section of Microsoft's walkthrough to see what that looks like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-binding-content-controls-to-custom-xml-parts?view=vs-2017#create-the-xml-data-file)

Next, you need to have the Developer tab visible.
Go to "File" > "Options" > "Customize Ribbon", and check the box next to "Developer". Then click OK.

Now, go to the Developer tab, and click "XML Mapping Pane", open the drop down list labeled "Custom XML Part:", click "(Add new part...)", and in the window that appears, browse to and open the XML file you just created.

Then you need to open the "Custom XML Part:" drop down list again, and choose the new entry you just added, which will show the properties you put into the XML file.

Finally, click where you want to use one of these new properties in the document, then right-click the property you want to use there, and pick what kind of content control you want from the "Insert Content Control" list.

The content controls are described in a [blog post by Brian Jones](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_jones/2006/01/09/create-a-rich-word-document-based-on-your-own-custom-xml-without-the-need-for-xslt/) <sub><sup>(about a doc that didn't work for me)</sup></sub> as:

> **Plain Text** - The name is somewhat misleading. This control will take
>   on the formatting that is applied to it while in design mode, so the
>   template author can set up the look, and the end user can only edit
>   the contents.
>
> **Picture** - This control can only contain a picture. When the user
>   clicks on it, the "insert picture" dialog appears.
>
> **Drop Down List** - This one behaves similarly to the plain text control,
>   since you can first set up what formatting you want applied, but in
>   addition, you can also specify a list of values that the user is
>   allowed to choose from.
>
> **Calendar** [Date Picker] - The user will be given a calendar control to pick the date.
>   You have a number of options here for how the date is formatted
>   (M/d/yyyy; dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy; etc.).
>
> **Combo Box** - Just like a Drop Down List, except that the user can type
>   in their own values as well as choose from a list you define.
>
> **Rich Text** - Behaves just like any other text in Word.

Also, to use the "Combo Box" and "Dropdown List" types, it looks like you have to create and attach an XML Schema to your document, which I haven't taken the time to fully read/comprehend/grok yet. For more information about doing so, see the relevant portions of [Microsoft's walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-binding-content-controls-to-custom-xml-parts?view=vs-2017), which uses Visual Studio, but is still a good reference for people doing this by hand.

Comment: Note: These properties also won't show up in the "Insert" > "Quick Parts" > "Document Properties" list, but they can be added to the document via "Developer" > "XML Mapping Pane", and once added they behave as described.

Answer (score 0):

This is the hack we've been looking for!!

http://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm

Take existing "Content Controls" that aren't useful (e.g., "Abstract") and rename them... the compromise is that they will not appear in the QuickParts->dropdown (will still show as "Abstract")... but if you copy and paste the one you modified... then the little "flag" above the original and the copies are all named the same.

Not perfect... but no coding.

In that tutorial, he leaves out one small step:
To change the placeholder text, go to Developer tab (which you might need to expose ... surely you know how to do that if you are reading this) and then click into the content control and hit the "Design Mode" button within the "Controls" part of the Developer tab.